# SQLite insert performance

Tags: sqlite

I need to write single lines to a file placed on a file server. I am considering utilizing SQLite to ensure that the writing of the line was successful and not just partially completed. However, as insert performance is really essential. My question is, what is the exact process (as it read this, write that, read this and so on) that SQLite goes through when it inserts a row to a table. The table does not have any indexes, nor primary keys, constraints or anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the most common bottleneck in my experience:

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19

Except for that, SQLite is really fast. :)

Comment: Do you know how many rounds the diskdrive will need to spin if a line is just added to a file?

Comment: That depends on the amount of data that is INSERTed, but most of the cases it is *at least* one revolution (unless you are in a transaction, because that's mostly memory based). After that the *COMMIT* will need at least one rotation, too.

Comment: OMG, best link ever

Answer (score 10):

You should use transactions and thus try to avoid `fsync()`-ing on every `INSERT`. Take a look [here](http://www.sqlite.org/speed.html) for some benchmarks.

Also, be sure to properly set the two important `pragmas`:

- [synchronous](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) (`NORMAL`)
- [journal_mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) (`WAL`)

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot in my issue. Ty

Comment: Thanks. Executing this command at the start of a bulk import gave me a huge speed increase: `PRAGMA synchronous = 0`

Comment: this a million times :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use explain for details what happens when you execute a statement: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html

Comment: But explain is normally not detailed enough to see every read and write made. It just states whether an index was utilized etc.